# Libgdx | Framebuffer not displaying anything when drawn

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am trying to draw a bunch of tiles (10,000 sprites) for a minimap. It lags on android when drawing individually, so I am trying to use a framebuffer. For some reason, I can't get anything drawn to the screen with the buffer. I will show the relevant code.

```
buffer = new FrameBuffer(Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888, Main.VIRTUAL_WORLD_WIDTH, Main.VIRTUAL_WORLD_HEIGHT, false);

    OrthographicCamera cam = new OrthographicCamera(Main.VIRTUAL_WORLD_WIDTH, Main.VIRTUAL_WORLD_HEIGHT); 
    buffer.begin();
    batch.begin();
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
    for(Tile[] tiles : world.level.getGrid()){
        for(Tile tile : tiles){
            tile.getSprite().draw(batch);
        }
    }
    batch.end();
    buffer.end();

    tiles = new Sprite(buffer.getColorBufferTexture());
```

The above code creates the framebuffer in the create method.

And this renders

```
batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
        batch.begin();
        tiles.draw(batch);
        batch.end();
```

Note, The position of the tiles sprite is 0, 0. I have tried changing all kids of stuff with this code, but can never get it to draw on the screen. The actual tiles aren't a problem, they all function correctly. My camera is setup correctly, so are my viewports.

Comment: When you draw the map to the buffer, you are forgetting to set a projection matrix. You can temporarily set an OrthographicCamera to the size of your world and use that.

Comment: @tenfour04 Edited code, still doesn't display :\

Comment: @tenfour04 Have an idea what's up?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code above.

Comment: @tenfour04 very odd :|